# jQuery Printing to the Screen

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I have a problem with displaying a message to the screen using jQuery.
This is the code that I have :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").submit(function(evt){
        value= $('#input').val();
        if(value == null || value == 0 || isNaN(value)) {
            alert("Input Error, Please Try Again");
        }
        else
        value=value*2.20462262;
        alert(value);

    });

});
```

I can do it with alerts but I need it to directly write to the screen in a space called answer.

Please Help :)

Comment: Did you mean this? _$("#answer").html(value);_ ... I would recommend _console.log()_ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume your `#singup` element is a form, since you are calling a submit event on it. Forms have a standard submit event, so when you click on that ol' submit button, they'll execute whatever they're set to (in most cases, what's in the action attribute). If you want to do something OTHER than the default, you call jQuery's `preventDefault()` so you, well, prevent the default action. From here on, you do pretty much whatever you wanna do. In your case, you can append the value you get from the input field to the `#answer` box or div or whatever.

So, your js would look something like:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signup").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        value= $('#field').val();
        $('#answer').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
    });
});`

And in your HTML you have a `#singup` form, a `#field` input, and your requested `#answer` area. Here's a [working pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/emQPKZ).

Hope it helps! =)